# Inverted View in VR sphere in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I've been trying to project a 360 video inside a Sphere with flipped normals for Google Cardboard VR. The Video works fine, only it is inverted horizontally, which is noticeable only when there is some text on the screen. I've included a screen shot of video and a UI.Text element in front of it to compare it with.

[image: Screenshot of Video]

I've tried to invert the view of the camera through projectionMatrix but then it just ends up in blank space. Screenshot : [image: Screenshot of Inverted Camera]

I can't figure out a way to make the video project the right way. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flipping the normals on a sphere is insufficient, you also need to reverse the U part of the UV coordinates (that is, change all the values `U` such that they are `1-U`).  A sphere is set up so that the outside renders text correctly from right to left. When you flip the normals "right" is still on the right from the outside...meaning that it's on the *left* when viewed from the inside.

You will either need to manually edit the UV coordinates yourself or get a premade inverted sphere off the asset store (IIRC there are two that are available for free).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a shader that displays the content correctly without inverting it, I have tested it with Unity 2018.1.1 as I am currently using it in my project:

```
Shader "InsideVisible" {
Properties {
    _MainTex ("Base (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
}

SubShader {
    Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
    Cull front    // ADDED BY BERNIE, TO FLIP THE SURFACES
    LOD 100

    Pass {  
        CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata_t {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f {
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
                half2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            sampler2D _MainTex;
            float4 _MainTex_ST;

            v2f vert (appdata_t v) {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                // ADDED BY BERNIE:
                v.texcoord.x = 1 - v.texcoord.x;                
                o.texcoord = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.texcoord, _MainTex);
                return o;
            }

            fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target {
                fixed4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, i.texcoord);
                return col;
            }
        ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

If you need more information about the shader you can view [this tutorial](http://bernieroehl.com/360stereoinunity/).